# Excel vba to scan dates and copy matched elements to the second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba but after a lot of Googling and not being successful to find a solution I decided to post my question here.

My worksheet has a column with dates in the mm/dd/yyyy format and its respective data in other columns. There is a start date and end date input field in the second worksheet. I need a macro that scans for a date range in the first sheet and displays all the matching results in the second sheet.

For example if the user enters a date  range of 01/01/2014 to 01/20/2014 in both the input fields, in the second worksheet, the macro should scan the column containing the dates in the first worksheet and pull its respective row values in the second worksheet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pertinent to you case, Excel worksheet functions can do the job: the test formula for inclusion will be like `==IF(AND(Sheet1!A1>"1/1/2014", Sheet1!A1<"1/20/2014"),Sheet1!A1,"")`. The same logic applies to other corresponding columns. Rgds,

Comment: This looks like a formula WV entered in the formula bar. Is this and a macro same. Sorry if my question is totally stupid. And how to copy the contents of other columns

Comment: Correct, this is an Excel Worksheet Formula. You do not need VBA in case of using this formula, just enter it in corresponding cells in Sheet2 and they will display the results based on your condition. Rgds,

Answer (score 1):

You should not care about the date format because dates are stored as a floating point representing the number of days since 01/01/1970. Just treat the values you get from the cells as a date in VBA and use the date functions to manipulate them.